# Broadcast reciever not working from service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am trying to use `BroadcastReceiver` inside my service but it is not working properly.

I am starting my service in an onCreate in my activity. Then in the services onCreate I am calling the following to register the Broadcast reciever:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    registerReceiver(DataUpdateReceiver, filter);
```

Here's the broadcast receiver i am trying to register:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver DataUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
};
```

Then else where in the Activity I am trying to call this so therefor the Toast message will be displayed.

```
            Intent i = new Intent();
            sendBroadcast(i);
```

But the Toast is not being displayed, I have also tried logging but nothing shows up. If anyone could help me out on this it would be appreciated, ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you have to specify action (or actions), which fire `onReceive()` method. Something like this might help you:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("some_action");
registerReceiver(DataUpdateReceiver, filter);

...

Intent i = new Intent("some_action");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare on top of the class

```
public final static String MY_RECEIVER_START = "com.yourcompanyname.appname.MY_RECEIVER_START";

private Radio radio;
```

In the service constructor

```
    //Initiate our receiver
    radio = new Radio();

    //Activate our recevier
    context.registerReceiver(radio, new IntentFilter(MY_RECEIVER_START));
```

Also in the service, create the receiver class and the method which shows toast

```
/**
 * Receiver Class
 * This setup checks for the incoming intent action to be able to
 * attach more messages to one receiver.
 */
private class Radio extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(MY_RECEIVER_START)){
            //show toast


        }

    }
}
```

After from anywhere in the application send message to our radio

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.yourcompanyname.appname.MY_RECEIVER_START"));
```